# Docker separation of processes and source code control

Tags: php, nginx, docker

I am trying to wrap my head around an optimal structure for Dockerization of a web app. So one of the best practices recommendations for using Docker is having [one process per container](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/). So where do I put the source code of my app?

Assume I am making a simple nginx and php app. The one process per container rule suggests having a `nginx` container that serves static assets and proxies php requests to a `php-fpm` container.

Now where do I put the source code? Do I keep it in a separate container and use `volumes_from` in Docker compose to let the two containers access the code? Or do I build each container with the source code inside (I suppose that makes it easier with versioning)?

What are the best practices around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I keep it in a separate container and use volumes_from in Docker compose to let the two containers access the code?

That is the usual best-practice, which avoid duplicating/synchronizing codes between components.
See "[Creating and mounting a data volume container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container)".

This is not just for pure data, but also for other shared resources like libraries, as shown in this article "[How to Create a Persistent Ruby Gems Container with Docker](http://www.atlashealth.com/blog/2014/09/persistent-ruby-gems-docker-container/#.VnSK7OK_Z64)":

[image: http://cdn.atlashealth.com/wp-content/uploads/docker-shared-gems.png]

Comment: Thank you. The article you linked definitely cleared up a few things!